# Premiere: Waveforms missing on nested sequences

Tags: premiere

So, I have nested some audio tracks and now the nested sequences look like this:

[image: picture of sequneces with no visible waveform]

How do I get premiere to display my waveforms in the timeline again? Because this is not very helpful ... to say the least.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you nest a sequence with more than one audio clip, your nested sequence will not have a single waveform to reference.

To generate the waveforms you must select the nested sequence and go to *Sequence > Render Audio* in the top menu bar.

Comment: is there some way to do that in the background? Premiere wants me to sit there for 1,5 h ...

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry. You might want to check the bitrate of your track audio and project audio match as Premiere will spend extra time converting the bitrate with 'Audio Render'.

Answer (score 0):

In the newer Premiere versions doesnt happen - you might get a waveform visible even with more nested layers inside - BUT the point is NOT TO HAVE ANY EFFECTS APPLIED ON THEM. In this case you have to render and that makes sense. Apply effects only on the whole nested sequnces.

cheers